# pyparsing recursive grammar space separated list inside a comma separated list

Tags: recursion, pyparsing

Have the following string that I'd like to parse:

```
((K00134,K00150) K00927,K11389) (K00234,K00235)
```

each step is separated by a space and alternation is represented by a comma. I'm stuck in the first part of the string where there is a space inside the brackets. The desired output I'm looking for is:

```
[[['K00134', 'K00150'], 'K00927'], 'K11389'], ['K00234', 'K00235']
```

What I've got so far is a basic setup to do recursive parsing, but I'm stumped on how to code in a space separated list into the bracket expression

```
from pyparsing import Word, Literal, Combine, nums, \
    Suppress, delimitedList, Group, Forward, ZeroOrMore

ortholog = Combine(Literal('K') + Word(nums, exact=5))
exp = Forward()
ortholog_group = Suppress('(') + Group(delimitedList(ortholog)) + Suppress(')')
atom = ortholog | ortholog_group | Group(Suppress('(') + exp + Suppress(')'))
exp <<= atom + ZeroOrMore(exp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but I think you only need one place where you include grouping with ()'s, not two.

```
import pyparsing as pp 

LPAR,RPAR = map(pp.Suppress, "()")
ortholog = pp.Combine('K' + pp.Word(pp.nums, exact=5))

ortholog_group = pp.Forward()
ortholog_group <<= pp.Group(LPAR + pp.OneOrMore(ortholog_group | pp.delimitedList(ortholog)) + RPAR)
expr = pp.OneOrMore(ortholog_group)

tests = """\
((K00134,K00150) K00927,K11389) (K00234,K00235)
"""
expr.runTests(tests)
```

gives:

```
((K00134,K00150) K00927,K11389) (K00234,K00235)
[[['K00134', 'K00150'], 'K00927', 'K11389'], ['K00234', 'K00235']]
[0]:
  [['K00134', 'K00150'], 'K00927', 'K11389']
  [0]:
    ['K00134', 'K00150']
  [1]:
    K00927
  [2]:
    K11389
[1]:
  ['K00234', 'K00235']
```

This is not exactly what you said you were looking for:

```
you wanted: [[['K00134', 'K00150'], 'K00927'], 'K11389'], ['K00234', 'K00235']
I output  : [[['K00134', 'K00150'], 'K00927', 'K11389'], ['K00234', 'K00235']]
```

I'm not sure why there is grouping in your desired output around the space-separated part `(K00134,K00150) K00927`. Is this your intention or a typo? If intentional, you'll need to rework the definition of `ortholog_group`, something that will do a delimited list of space-delimited groups in addition to the grouping at parens. The closest I could get was this:

```
[[[[['K00134', 'K00150']], 'K00927'], ['K11389']], [['K00234', 'K00235']]]
```

which required some shenanigans to group on spaces, but not group bare orthologs when grouped with other groups. Here is what it looked like:

```
ortholog_group <<= pp.Group(LPAR + pp.delimitedList(pp.Group(ortholog_group*(1,) & ortholog*(0,))) + RPAR) | pp.delimitedList(ortholog)
```

The `&` operator in combination with the repetition operators gives the space-delimited grouping (`*(1,)` is equivalent to `OneOrMore`, `*(0,)` with `ZeroOrMore`, but also supports `*(10,)` for "10 or more", or `*(3,5)` for "at least 3 and no more than 5"). This too is not quite exactly what you asked for, but may get you closer if indeed you need to group the space-delimited bits.

But I must say that grouping on spaces is ambiguous - or at least confusing.  Should "(A,B) C D" be `[[A,B],C,D]` or `[[A,B],C],[D]` or `[[A,B],[C,D]]`? I think, if possible, you should permit comma-delimited lists, and *perhaps* space-delimited also, but require the ()'s when items should be grouped.

Comment: There was no typo about the space and sadly I didn't make the grammar and I'm not able to change anything about it. I'm trying to scrape this information off a website and turn it into more usable data. The grouping should be [[A,B],C],[D]. I found that your second code block throws an error on my computer, does it pass the test on yours?

Comment: Yes, it worked on mine, that is how I generated that last example. What error did you get?

Comment: `((K00134,K00150) K00927,K11389) (K00234,K00235)
     ^
    FAIL: Expected {Group:({Suppress:("(") Group:({{Forward: ...}... & 
    [Combine:({"K" W:(0123...)})]...}) [{Suppress:(",") Group:({{Forward: ...}... 
    & [Combine:({"K" W:(0123...)})]...})}]... Suppress:(")")}) | Combine:({"K" W:
    (0123...)}) [, Combine:({"K" W:(0123...)})]...} (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)`   I'm using version 2.1.4 of pyparsing with python 3.5